# OWASP Dependency Check determines wrong artifacts

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, owasp

I'm using the [Maven Plugin](http://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/index.html) of the [OWASP Dependency Check](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Dependency_Check) in a multimodule project.

There is a Module with the `artifactId` *"links"* and another (I will call it *"war"*) module with a dependency on this module. Both have the `groupId` *"de.mygroup"*.

When I now run `mvn dependency-check-maven:check` I get the following warning:

```
links-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (cpe:/a:hot_links:hot_links:5.0.0, cpe:/a:links:links:5.0.0, de.mygroup:links:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT) : CVE-2006-7086
```

As I understood this warning, this is a false positive because the dependency check only looks for the `artifactId` regardless `groupId`. Is this correct?

Is there anything I can do to tell the plugin which one I'm using? But I think it should determine this automatically.

I've looked inside the source code of the maven plugin and in [`BaseDependencyCheckMojo.java:652`](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/blob/master/dependency-check-maven/src/main/java/org/owasp/dependencycheck/maven/BaseDependencyCheckMojo.java#L652) I've found `dependencyNode.getArtifact().getId()` But this should return the full quallified coordinates of the artifacts. So I don't understand why it found multiple "candidates" which it then uses to search for vulnerabilities.

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: I've just tested with the current [`master` from GitHub](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck) because I've seen that there are some changes in the determination of the dependencies. The Warning above is gone now.
But I have a third module with the `artifactId` *"indesign"* (and the `groupId` *"de.mygroup"*) and for this I get this warning:

```
indesign-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (cpe:/a:adobe:indesign:5.0.0, de.mygroup:indesign:5.0.0-SNAPSHOT) : CVE-2006-0525
```

I think this is the same problem but I don't understand why the first warning is gone and the second one is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered on the project's github issues list (see issue [#550](https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/550)).

Comment: Hello!
Link only answers, though perfectly viable are discouraged on stackoverflow. Could you please enrich your answer with excerpt copied from linked site?